# Console output mixed with X Screen after 12.04 Upgrade

Tags: console, multiseat

I've just upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and I'm seeing console output on my X screen.  It's not legible but sometimes I can even see the cursor blinking.  I'm also running a multi-seat system and I see garbage on the screen when someone types on the second keyboard as well.  Clicking on the screen erases the garbage console output but it comes right back when someone starts typing.

### xorg.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Desktop"
    Screen      0  "DesktopScreen" 0 0
    InputDevice    "DesktopMouse"          "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "DesktopKeyboard"       "CoreKeyboard"
    Option         "AutoAddDevices"        "false"
    Option         "AllowEmptyInput"       "true"
    Option         "AutoEnableDevices"     "false"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Desktop2"
    Screen      1  "Desktop2Screen" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Desktop2Mouse"          "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Desktop2Keyboard"       "CoreKeyboard"
    Option         "AutoAddDevices"        "false"
    Option         "AllowEmptyInput"       "true"
    Option         "AutoEnableDevices"     "false"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "AutoAddDevices"     "false"
    Option "AutoEnableDevices"  "false"
    Option "AllowMouseOpenFail" "on"
    Option "AllowEmptyInput"    "on"
    Option "ZapWarning"         "on"
    Option "HandleSepcialKeys"  "off" # Zapping on
    Option "DRI2"               "on"
    Option "Xinerama"           "0"
EndSection

# Desktop Mouse
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "DesktopMouse"
    Driver         "evdev"
    Option         "Device"          "/dev/input/event3"
    Option         "Protocol"        "auto"
    Option         "GrabDevice"      "on"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "Buttons"         "5"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping"    "4 5"
    Option         "SendCoreEvents"  "true"
EndSection

# Desktop2 Mouse
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Desktop2Mouse"
    Driver         "evdev"
    Option         "Device"          "/dev/input/event5"
    Option         "Protocol"        "auto"
    Option         "GrabDevice"      "on"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "Buttons"         "5"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping"    "4 5"
    Option         "SendCoreEvents"  "true"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "DesktopKeyboard"
    Driver         "evdev"
    Option         "Device"    "/dev/input/event4"
    Option         "XkbRules"  "xorg"
    Option         "XkbModel"  "105"
    Option         "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option         "Protocol"  "Standard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Desktop2Keyboard"
    Driver         "evdev"
    Option         "Device"    "/dev/input/event14"
    Option         "XkbRules"  "xorg"
    Option         "XkbModel"  "105"
    Option         "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option         "Protocol"  "Standard"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Desktop2Monitor"
    VendorName     "Acer"
    ModelName      "Acer G235H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "DesktopMonitor"
    VendorName     "Acer"
    ModelName      "Acer H213H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "EVGACard"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 560 Ti"
    Option         "Coolbits" "1"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "XFXCard"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 9800"
    Option         "Coolbits" "1"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "DesktopScreen"
    Device         "EVGACard"
    Monitor        "DesktopMonitor"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Desktop2Screen"
    Device         "XFXCard"
    Monitor        "Desktop2Monitor"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

### lightdm.conf

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
#greeter-session=lightdm-razor-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
xserver-allow-tcp=false
xserver-pass-seat-name=true
greeter-pass-seat-id=true

[Seat:0]
xserver-layout=Desktop
xserver-command=/usr/bin/X :0 -layout Desktop -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt8 -novtswitch -sharevts -background none

[Seat:1]
xserver-layout=Desktop2
xserver-command=/usr/bin/X :1 -layout Desktop2 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp vt9 -novtswitch -sharevts
```

.

Answer (score 1):

So far it seems like the GrabDevice option solved it.  I added:

```
Option         "GrabDevice" "on"
```

to the keyboard section of xorg.conf.

Comment: Anyone having this issue (or even just using multiseat) should upgrade lightdm to 1.3.3.  1.2.1 (which comes with 12.04 currently) is exceptionally buggy.